# UITableView infinite scrolling like a wheel

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have 2 `UITableViews` in a single `View Controller` which represent a 23 cells hours table view and 60 cells minutes table view. What i want to achieve is i can scroll both table view like rolling wheel like when we have scrolled to the end, it can still be scrollable to the first table view by scrolling bottom and vice versa.

I found something like this : `https://github.com/bharath2020/UITableViewTricks/tree/master/CircleView/BBTableView` , but too bad it's in `Obj-c`.

I want to be able to achieve the following :

[image]

Where the hours and minutes can be scrolled infinitely like from `12 -> 0` or `59 -> 0`

How do i do something like that in swift?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://iphone2020.wordpress.com/tag/circular-tableview/) can help you understand the algorithm, beside, you can use obj-c in swift, whats the problem?

Comment: Please check this: https://github.com/pronebird/UIScrollView-InfiniteScroll

Comment: @Tj3n The problem is i don't really understand obj-c

Comment: @KamleshShingarakhiya It's more like reveal more stuff rather than wheel-like infinite-scrolling

Comment: @Orange check out a site called [objectivec2swift.com](https://objectivec2swift.com/)

Comment: Why not use UIPickerView for this purpose ?

Comment: @UmairAfzal Please post as an answer how should i use 2 `UIPickerView` with a colon between them and the PickerView can be scrolled infinitely

Comment: @Orange Please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Okay So just tested out for you. Here is an example for the circular  UIPickerView.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

let maxRows = 10
private let maxElements = 10000
@IBOutlet weak var myPickerView: UIPickerView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.myPickerView.dataSource = self;
    self.myPickerView.delegate = self;
    myPickerView.selectRow(maxElements / 2, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return maxElements
}


func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    let myRow = row % maxRows
    let myString = String(format: "%i", myRow)
    return myString
}

}
```

Now as far as creating a UIPickerPickerView with two components is concerned, You can find easily on google.

I hope it helps you to solve the problem.

Comment: What about the colon?

Comment: There can be multiple possible solutions for the colon, for example plcae a label between two UIPickerViews.